# How to correct my dataset so charts.js bar graph will stack

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart with charts.js and an ajax call for data, but it will only create a regular bar chart.

I suspect my array is not in the correct format.

Here is the value of `data`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtnTT.png

```
function doCharts(stat) {
 $.ajax({
    url: "data.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {
        id: stat
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var stat_name = [];
        var stat_count = [];

        for(var i in data) {                
            stat_name.push(data[i].stat_name);
            stat_count.push(data[i].stat_count);
            }


        var chartdata = {
            labels: stat_name,
            datasets : [
                {
                    data: stat_count                
                }
            ]
        };              

        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");

        var inScreening = new Chart(ctx, {

            type: 'bar',
            data: chartdata,
             options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ 
        stacked: true, 
        gridLines: { display: false },
        }],
      yAxes: [{ 
        stacked: true,  
        }],
    },
    legend: {display: false}
}

            });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

};

Here is what it produces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG3O5.png

I would like all those separate bars stacked into one.

Comment: Did you try to make a data set for each value instead of having them all in one? I'm pretty sure that is how it works.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel how can I split out that JSON into separate datasets?

Comment: Try something like `datasets: stat_count.map(count => ({ data: [count] }))`

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel that worked great, thanks. But when I tried to do the same for labels e.g. `labels: stat_name.map(name => ({ data: [name] })),
    datasets: stat_count.map(count => ({ data: [count] }))` I just get [object Object] repeatedly. Why is this?

Comment: The labels just need to be the array as you had it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the labels will be an array of your `data` elements `stat_name` property and there will be a data set for each entry of your `data`. You can clean much of the processing of the `data` into the below:

```js
const chartdata = {
    labels: data.map(item => item.stat_name),
    datasets: data.map(item => ({ data: item.stat_count }));
};
```